# Hibernate Envers : Entity not found on a ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

When upgrading Hibernate from 3.3.2.GA to 4.3.11.Final, i've got an "EntityNotFoundException" when querying on audit tables.

My model :

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class A {
   [...]
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", nullable = false)
   private EntityB entityB;
   [...]
}

@Entity
@Audited
public class B {
   [...]
}
```

When i check audit tables in database (SQLServer), i see the reason of my exception.

```
select * from A_AUD where id = 1  => 1 result with VER_REV = 100 (and B_ID = 10)
select * from B_AUD where id = 10 => 2 results with VER_REV = 200 and 300
```

When i try to load with JPA :

```
getAuditReader( anEntityManager ).createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity( A.class false, true ).add( AuditEntity.id().eq( 1) );
```

Hibernate is lazy loading B_AUD. But in the query, he's checking VER_REV <= 100.
And no result can be found.

Is it a problem of my datas that was not check in hibernate 3 ?
Or this can be resolved in the code ?

I've found some answers elements like in https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8093 but i can't find the "good practice" for this problem.
Updating VER_REV in database may have impacts on others entities (my model is a bit complex). And "patching" Envers must be the last solution only.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Could you include the configuration settings you are bootstrapping with that are Hibernate Envers specific?  Could you also include the precise mapping from the `EntityB` side for the collection in your post?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a problem of my datas that was not check in hibernate 3 ? Or this can be resolved in the code?

This isn't necessarily a code problem or a data problem.

The scenario you mentioned can easily occur when entity `A` is modified but that modification doesn't impact the state of entity `B` and so the first revision only causes entity `A` to have a revision record stored, e.g. VER_REV = 100.

Later on at some future point in time, two more modifications occured that changed entity `B` but much like the former scenario, these changes do not impact entity `A`, hence why these entity `B` changes have VER_REV = 200 and VER_REV = 300.

I added a comment and can update this answer with more specific details once I get more of an understanding of your configuration & mappings.

Comment: I have the same problem, does it fix in Hibernate 5?

Comment: In my case, as long as the relationship entity (OneToOne, ManyToOne) is set to be audited, then querying vertically produces "id not found" issue. Setting the respective column to @NotAudited fix the issue, but I want the column in relation to be audited as well.